# Center text relative to other element?

Tags: css, image

I want to have a row of image links with text below them, with the text centered to the image, similar to the product selector on [apple's website](http://apple.com/mac). Is there a way to do this without making a div for every "item" and centering it within the div? HTML/CSS strict would be nice, but Javascript, jQuery, etc would be fine.

Comment: You didn't post any code ... but isn't that exactly what CSS and CSS classes are for?

Comment: JavaScript would be senseless.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't know what my code would be. What do you mean that's what they're for? Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Comment: You can't get simpler than `<a><img>Some Text</a>`. You need to contain the `img` and text for each "item" in *something*...

Comment: @thirtydot the text and images are already in a div, is there a way to make a div continue to use it's parent div's css properties, except width/height?

Comment: Q: What have you tried?  Q: If you're not already familiar with CSS, would you be willing to invest a little time in some on-line tutorials: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss/firstcss.en.html?  Book recommendation: [HTML and CSS Web Standards Solutions](http://www.amazon.com/HTML-CSS-Standards-Solutions-Standardistas/dp/1430216069), Nicklas Persson & Christopher Murphy.  IMHO...

Comment: Q: Is there a way to make a div continue to use it's parent div's css properties?  A: That's the "cascading" part of CSS ;)  Q: Except width/height?  A: That's what classes (and subclasses, and/or child elements) are for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't specifically need to be a `<div>`, it can be any element that has `display: inline-block` (or `block`, but then you 'd have to float them to line them up in the same row).

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/znByV/)**.